# What mistake would trigger a diagnostic using this option in R Studio?

Tags: r, rstudio, diagnostics, optionmenu, non-standard-evaluation

In the Global Options of R Studio, under the Code Panel and Diagnostics Tab, there's an option that reads "Enable diagnostics within R function calls."

I had assumed that this option would trigger diagnostic warnings any time one made a mistake within a function call. For example, if I accidentally omit a comma between arguments, I get a diagnostic warning:
`c(x, rep(y each = 3))`

*However, this warning appears in this instance whether I have the option mentioned above on or off.*

When you Google this option, you get a lot of hits from people also wondering what this option does. See [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/meaning-of-option-enable-diagnostics-within-r-function-calls/157418). You also get a lot of hits describing this option with this exact text:

> Controls whether diagnostics are performed within function calls, e.g. dplyr::select(mtcars, mpg, cyl). Toggle this if your code makes heavy use of non-standard evaluation, and RStudio is unable to produce correct diagnostics for you.

See [here](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/205753617-Code-Diagnostics-in-the-RStudio-IDE) as one example.

I've tried reading [Hadley Wickham's article on what non-standard evaluation is](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html), and I tried "breaking" the functions he shows in that article to see if I could come up with an example of this option triggering a diagnostic warning that wouldn't already come up, and I was unsuccessful.

**Can someone show an example of a mistake that trigger this *specific* option to trigger, i.e. the warning comes up *only* if this option is checked and not if it isn't?**